# Unable to insert values into Oracle database fetched from XML file in Apache Camel

Tags: oracle, apache-camel, stringbuilder

I am making a proof of concept to insert XML values into an Oracle database. I am using StringBuilder in Java to insert values. My Camel context is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="
                     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

              <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"/>
                <property name="username" value="system"/>
                <property name="password" value="1234"/>
              </bean>
             <bean id="orderToSQL" class="camel.project.camel.system.OrderToSQLBean" />
             <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
                <route>
               <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
                    <choice>
                        <when>
                            <xpath>/person/city = 'London'</xpath>
                            <log message="UK message"/>
                            <to uri="file:target/messages/uk"/>
                        </when>
                        <when>
                            <xpath>/person/city = 'Charleston'</xpath>
                            <log message="US message"/>
                            <to uri="bean:orderToSQL?method=toSql"/>
                        </when>
                        <otherwise>
                            <log message="Other message"/>
                            <to uri="file:target/messages/others"/>
                        </otherwise>
                    </choice>
                </route>
            </camelContext>
             </beans>
```

So whenever a message with city Charleston comes I have to write data in that XML to the Oracle database. I am using a Java class as shown below. It's not throwing any kind of errors but its unable to insert values into the database.

```
     package camel.project.camel.system;
        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.sql.Statement;
        import javax.sql.DataSource;
        import org.apache.camel.language.XPath;

        public class OrderToSQLBean {

            /**
             * @param args
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                 try {
                     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" );
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.err.println("ERROR: failed to load JDBC driver.");
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     try {
                        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","tcs#1234");
                        Statement st = null;
                        ResultSet rs = null;
                        st = c.createStatement(); 
                        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT *from people;"); 
                        dump(rs);
                        st.close();    
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
            public static void dump(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                ResultSetMetaData meta   = rs.getMetaData();
                int colmax = meta.getColumnCount();
                int i;
                Object o = null;
                for (; rs.next(); ) {
                    for (i = 0; i < colmax; ++i) {
                        o = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                        System.out.print(o.toString() + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }  
            public String toSql(@XPath("person/firstName") String firstName,
                @XPath("person/lastName") String lastName,
                @XPath("person/city") String city)
            {   

               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append("insert into people");
               sb.append("(country, lastname, firstname, city) values (");
               sb.append("'US', ");
               sb.append("'").append(lastName).append("', ");
               sb.append("'").append(firstName).append("', ");
               sb.append("'").append(city).append("'); ");
               System.out.println("String = " +sb);
               return sb.toString();
            }

        }
```

This is the output I am geting in my console:

```
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.spring.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.0.redhat-60024 starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ClassPathXmlApplicationContext INFO  Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2cbe08: startup date [Fri Sep 05 15:50:42 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] XmlBeanDefinitionReader        INFO  Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\761285\Desktop\New Workspace\camel-system\target\classes\META-INF\spring\configuration.xml]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] XmlBeanDefinitionReader        INFO  Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\761285\Desktop\New Workspace\camel-system\target\classes\META-INF\spring\xmltodb-context.xml]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultListableBeanFactory     INFO  Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=close; defined in file [C:\Users\761285\Desktop\New Workspace\camel-system\target\classes\META-INF\spring\configuration.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\761285\Desktop\New Workspace\camel-system\target\classes\META-INF\spring\xmltodb-context.xml]]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultListableBeanFactory     INFO  Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10b2840: defining beans [dataSource,orderToSQL,template,consumerTemplate,camel-1:beanPostProcessor,camel-1]; root of factory hierarchy
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SingleConnectionDataSource     INFO  Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.0.redhat-60024 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ManagementStrategyFactory      INFO  JMX enabled.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 175 type converters
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] FileEndpoint                   INFO  Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] FileEndpoint                   INFO  Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size: 1000
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] XPathBuilder                   INFO  Created default XPathFactory com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@1b792e0
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://src/data?noop=true]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ultManagementLifecycleStrategy INFO  StatisticsLevel at All so enabling load performance statistics
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.0.redhat-60024 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.319 seconds
[1) thread #0 - file://src/data] route1                         INFO  UK message
[1) thread #0 - file://src/data] route1                         INFO  Other message
[1) thread #0 - file://src/data] route1                         INFO  US message
```

I am printing the String i am getting by stringbuilder the query generated is in correct syntax of oracle database query

```
String = insert into people(country, lastname, firstname, city) values ('US', 'Peeples', 'Kenneth', 'Charleston');
```

Please help me resolving this issue. I am not using any blueprint XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that you aren't seeing any errors. Both your select and insert have a trilling semi-colon though; that is a statement separator and not valid. Your insert should be:

```
String = insert into people(country, lastname, firstname, city)
values ('US', 'Peeples', 'Kenneth', 'Charleston')
```

... without the semicolon. Remove the one from your select too, which also needs a space added before the `from`:

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * from people");
```

You should be getting ORA-00911 for both statements, so maybe it isn't trying to execute them at all. You're returning `sb` but I'm not familiar with Camel so I don't know when or if anything actually executes what you returned, or if you're supposed to be executing that from within the `toSql()` method.

You should also be using prepared statements and bind variables rather than putting the fixed values into the string via the StringBuilder, but that's slightly out of scope of the question. You should read up on SQL injection though.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply Alex Poole...could you provide any piece of code for insert data into oracle db using stringbuilder..